# How I align my toc to the left when the chapter name is too big

Tags: table-of-contents, alignment, titletoc

This is my toc, I want to align the page number

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titletoc}




\titlecontents{chapter}[5.3em]{\vspace{0.1cm}}
{\hfill\thecontentslabel}
{}
{\ |\contentspage}[\smallskip] 

\titlecontents{part}[5.3em]{\vspace{1cm}}
{\hfill\Large\thecontentslabel}
{}
{\Large \ |\contentspage}[\vspace{1cm}]

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\part{Primeira parte}

\chapter{Um capitulo curto}
\chapter{Um capitulo mais longo apara se ver como acontece com a tableofcontents. lorem ipsum lorem ipsum}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you post a small compilable code illustrating your problem?  Also, do you really want the chapter titles to be flushright?

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just edited the original post.